# Dynamic C# Not rendering on page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, rendering, pageload

I have a method which is intended to dynamically generate a series of divs based on the entry of a value from a dropdown list. However, I wish to reuse the same code to generate the tables on the first page_load when a number already exists.

This is where the method is called. It is called GenerateTables and it is called from the Page_Load event:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        AcademicProgramme programme;
        if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
        {
            programme = academic.GetAcademicProgramme(Request.QueryString["id"]);
            programmeName.Text = programme.Name;
            PopulateView(programme);
            GenerateTables(programme.Levels);
        }
}
```

And here is the method itself (apologies for the size of the method):

```
private void GenerateTables(int count)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < count + 1; i++)
    {
        LiteralControl title = new LiteralControl();
        LiteralControl close = new LiteralControl();
        LiteralControl close2 = new LiteralControl();
        String script = "<div class=\"ModuleProgTable\"><h3>Level " + i + "</Modules></h3></br>";

        title.Text = script;
        AcademicTable.Controls.Add(title);

        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.ID = "Level" + i + "Modules";

        PopulatePanel(panel, GetModulesSession(i));

        Button a = new Button();
        a.ID = "AddModule" + i;
        a.Text = "Add Module";
        a.Click += (OpenPopup);

        AcademicTable.Controls.Add(panel);
        AcademicTable.Controls.Add(a);

        close.Text = "</div> <!-- Close here -->";
        close2.Text = "</div>";

        AcademicTable.Controls.Add(close);

    }
}
```

The divs are clearly being populated because if I change the dropdown option then they appear on the PostBack without fail. It's when I try to get them to render on the first page_load that I am having problems.

Any feedback and advice would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,
-Michael

Comment: Have you debugged it?

Comment: UPDATED: I have found a solution to the problem. It is probably not perfect design or practice but it works and, at this point, I'm grateful for that.

All I have done is add a new Javascript control on the page_load event to trigger a postback the first time the user accesses the page. Not optimal but it is a fix and at this point, I'll take it.

Sorry for wasting your time.

-Michael

Comment: Okay... Good luck with that!

Comment: Is the AutoEventWireup property of the page set to true?